# Haskel type declaration, function and tuple as arguments

Tags: haskell, ghci, winghci

I'm doing a haskell assignment for school. I want to make a function called MapTuple, wich maps a function with a tuple as its arguments for an array of tuple. Im declaring it on the following way:

```
MapTuple :: [(a,b)] -> (a -> b) -> [b]
```

the way i want to use  the function is as follows.

```
MapTuple :: [(Int, String)] -> (Int -> String) -> [String]
```

problem however is that I get the following error when compiling:

Invalid type signature: MapTuple :: ([(a, b)]) -> (a -> b) -> [b]
Should be of form  ::

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for helping me in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell has a naming convention that's actually part of the language

- Functions start with lower case
- Constructors start with upper case

So you need to change `MapTuple` to `mapTuple`

As for what a constructor is,

```
 data Foo = ThisIsAConstructor
```

It's basically a function that returns a `Foo`.